# ¿Cómo comentar las líneas seleccionadas en VSCode?

Tags: vscode

Me gustaría saber cómo comentar las líneas seleccionadas en VSCode y si es posible cómo cambiar el atajo de teclado.

Answer (score 24):

En la versión actualizada VSCode 1.27.2 la abreviatura Alternar bloquear comentario es:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shfit</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Te comparto que, en cuanto tengas 50 puntos de reputación, podrás [realizar comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Creo que tu respuesta es correcta, pero fue detectada como una publicación de baja calidad "por su poco contenido". En todo caso, te agradezco por tu aporte. Saludos.

Answer (score 16):

Segun esta la [documentacion oficial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) el atajo de teclado para esta accion es el siguiente:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

donde este es el nombre en concreto del comando que se le asocia es:

`editor.action.commentLine`

---

Pero en alguno OS es puede variar, si lo anterior no le funciona, puede dirigirse dentro de VSCode a:

`Archivo` -> `preferencias` -> `Metodos abreviados de teclado`.

al hacer click se le abrira una fichero con el nombre de `Keybindings.json` suele aparecer mas a la **izquierda** que otro con el mismo nombre que le suele aparecer mas a la **derecha**.

Ahora en el fichero de mas a la **izquierda** buscamos una linea que muestre lo siguiente:

```
"command": "editor.action.commentLine",
```

donde la linea entera seria algo asi:

```
{ "key": "aqui_apareceria_el_atajo_asociado_al_comando",                "command": "editor.action.commentLine", "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" },
```

---

Con lo anterio puede saber que atajo es el asociado para su OS.
Si desea cambiarlo copiamos las siguientes lineas:

```
{ "key": "atajo",    "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
                       "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" },
```

y ahora en el fichero que mencionamos que aparecia mas a la **derecha**, insertamos el texto copiado dentro de [ ], algo como esto;

Keybindings.json

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    {   "key": "ctrl+7",                
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

nota: No introduciomos la `,` que esta al final de `}` al hacer la copia (si tambien la copio) si esta insercion es la ultima que va ha realizar, de introducir algun otro cambio se añadiria `,` despues de la `}` que separara los distintos atajos de teclado.

nota1: Para descomentar es el mismo atajo pues este hace de `toggle`.

Answer (score 8):

En **Linux** se usan las siguientes combinaciones para comentar / descomentar código:

- Para comentar una sola línea o cada línea de un bloque: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> (NO requiere que el texto esté seleccionado, por defecto comenta la línea actual)
- Para hacer lo opuesto al paso anterior (descomentar): <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> (NO requiere que el texto esté seleccionado, por defecto comenta la línea actual)
- Para hacer un comentario en bloque: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> (Requiere selección)
- Cuando por algún motivo instalo alguna extensión y me daña los atajos de teclado utilizo <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> para abrir el listado de comandos disponibles y allí busco **Comment** o **Comentar**, dependiendo del idioma de instalación, por lo general allí dice cual combinación utilizar e incluso permite realizar la acción seleccionando alguna opción del listado.

Como sugerencia personal no cambiaría los atajos de teclado, ya que suelo estar cambiando de sistema operativo y no me gusta estar configurando muchas cosas de entrada, lo mejor es adaptarse a la forma establecida por cada herramienta.

Answer (score 3):

Se que la pregunta tiene algún tiempo pero puede ser de utilidad considerar:

Las combinaciones que normalmente utilizo son: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> y <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Algo que se hace a todas horas en los editores de código es comentar o des-comentar de golpe fragmentos enteros de código. Para hacerlo de manera rápida simplemente selecciona las líneas a comentar o descomentar y pulsa <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Ahora VS se queda a la espera de lo que quieres hacer con ellas, que puede ser comentarlas si pulsas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, o des-comentarlas si pulsas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (también puedes hacerlo sin soltar la tecla Ctrl entre el primer y segundo paso), o en su caso : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

**Esto puede variar según tu configuración, ya que Visual Studio trae varios "mapeados" de teclas y te pregunta tras la instalación cuál quieres utilizar. Puedes ver qué teclas tienes asignadas en cada caso buscando el comando en cuestión dentro del diálogo >*Herramientas* > *Personalización* y dentro de esta ventana en la pestaña *Comandos*, botón Teclado.**

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl + Mayus + A**
Lo encontré entrando a **Archivo -> preferencias -> Metodos abreviados de teclado** Con este atajo se puede comentar una línea o un bloque si así lo deseas.

Answer (score 2):

Los **atajos de teclado de VSCode para comentar código** se pueden consultar rápidamente desde el propio editor, accediendo a la paleta de comandos (Ctrl+Shift+P) y escribiendo "comment":

[image: Atajos de teclado de VSCODE para comentar código]

En mi caso:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Añadir línea comentario.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> - Eliminar línea comentario.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Añadir o eliminar bloque de comentario.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ç</kbd> - Añadir o eliminar bloque de comentario.

Para **modificar dichos atajos para comentar código**, pulsamos primero <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> para visualizarlos todos y a continuación filtramos escribiendo "comment", para finalmente, pulsando sobre el icono de edición, indicar nuestro propio atajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para **más información**, consultar [documentación "Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Version VSC: 1.37.1

Para comentar/descomentar un bloque o línea con '//' (si el documento es html automáticamente comentará entre <  ! --  --  > ), la combinación de teclas por defecto es: Ctrl + ç (no es necesaria selección previa para la línea).

Para comentar/descomentar un bloque o línea con '/* ... */' , la combinación de teclas por defecto es: Shift + alt + a

Para cambiarlo, como ya se ha comentado, Archivo -> preferencias -> Métodos abreviados de teclado.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciona la siguiente combinación de teclado:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ç</kbd>
o
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>

Primero selecciona el texto y usa la combinación, despues con la misma combinación puedes descomentar.

Answer (score 0):

Hay otra forma mas general.
No estoy seguro si sólo la tiene las versiones mas recientes ***Edit>> Toggle Line Comment***, o <kbd>Shift</kbd> + }

Esto no afecta si quieres agregar documentación a tu código.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso para comentar una línea sin seleccionarla con los caracteres **//**, utilizo <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> y sin soltar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> presiono <kbd>C</kbd>, también funciona para una selección de varias líneas, para quitar **//** de la línea o líneas comentadas presiono <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> y sin soltar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> presiono <kbd>U</kbd>, pero si necesito comentar o descomentar una selección entre  **/ ***  y  *** /**  utilizo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, o si necesito comentar o descomentar la línea en la que me encuentro entre  **/ ***  y  *** /** , presiono <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>, si uso este último en una selección depende de lo que haya seleccionado se comenta o descomenta con **//** o entre  **/ ***  y  *** /** , todo depende de lo que esté seleccionado, sugiero hacer pruebas para entender mejor ya que no hay algo mejor que la práctica.